# Function not working in PHP $_GET[]

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm working on a small catalogue which will take a list of products in a SQL database and list them on a catalogue.php page.  When you click on a product, you'll be taken to a page with that specific product.   So I have a productbuild.php which is the class that builds both the the catalogue and the individual product.   The individual product is located at productview.php.  I can view the products on the catalogue page but not on the productview page.

Here is my class:

```
require_once('connect.php');

        class Catalogue {   

            public $ksdb = '';


        public function __construct() {
            $this->ksdb = new Database;

            }
    //This function gets all the products on the main catalogue page, it works fine
            public function getProds() {
                $id = 0;
                //This is the prod array that is not being passed
                $prod = $return = array();
                $querystr = $this->ksdb->db_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM products"); 
                try {
                    $querystr->execute();
                    for($i=0; $row = $querystr->fetch(); $i++) {
                        $return[$i] = array();
                        foreach($row as $rowi => $rowitem) {
                            $return[$i][$rowi] = $rowitem;

                        }
                    }
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                return $return;
                //$prod = $return;
            }   



//This is the one that is not working on the productview.php page
            public function viewProd($prodID) {
                $prod = $return = array();
                $querystr = $this->ksdb->db_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID= ?");
                try {
                    $querystr->execute(array($id));
                    for ($i = 0; $row = $querystr->fetch(); $i++) {
                        $return[$i] = array();
                        foreach($row as $rowi => $rowitem) {
                            $return[$i][$rowi] = $rowitem;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                $prod = $return;
                $prod[0]['Description'] = $prod[0]['Description'];
                }
        }
```

And this is my productview.php page:

```
//Include the class
<?php include_once('/productbuild.php');

//Create an object of catalogue
$viewproduct = new Catalogue;


//if there is something in productview.php?ID= viewProd function is called
if(!empty($_GET['ID'])) {
    $prod = $viewproduct->viewProd($_GET['ID']);
    }
    else {
    echo "No Products";
    }

?>

//Echo the product name (from the DB) and Description
<h3><?php echo htmlspecialchars($prod['Name']); ?></h3>
  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($prod['Description']); ?>
```

Comment: 1 - What is the question?

Comment: 2 - Why do you have something like `$prod[0]['Description'] = $prod[0]['Description'];` in your code?

Comment: 3 - Why are you traversing an array to get a similar one if you could just do a "fetchAll" in getProds function?

Comment: As I said this is from a tutorial in a book, I just started learning PHP.  What would it look like to use fetchAll in getProds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing your viewProd function from

```
$querystr->execute(array($id));
```

to

```
$querystr->execute(array($prodID))
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: How about activating notices to get a message whenever an uninitialized variable gets used? `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: Naruto, thanks for your comment.   That did not work for me, it got rid of the error message from the foreach loop but nothing is displaying, and my var dump still states that $prodID is null.  I will keep messing around with this.

Comment: Your viewProd function is not returning anything. How about return $prod at the end of the function?